# How to disable auto hide navigation bar in cyanogenmod 11?

Tags: cyanogenmod, settings, user-interface, navigation-bar

The navigation bar is automatically hidden in Cyanogenmod 11. Maybe it's a good idea but my tablet case does not let me swipe from bottom to show it.

Is there a way to prevent a navigation bar from hiding so that it is always displayed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're talking about Expanded Desktops. Can't you disable it from the Power Menu?

[image]

*Image from [phandroid](http://phandroid.com/2012/10/29/cyanogenmod-10-hide-on-screen-buttons/).*

Comment: Many thanks! What a great place to hide this setting!)